# Importing XML with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to import an XML file with PostgreSQL 13. I've found a site that has this function:

```
create or replace function xml_import(filename text)
  returns xml
  volatile
  language plpgsql as
$f$
    declare
        content bytea;
        loid oid;
        lfd integer;
        lsize integer;
    begin
        loid := lo_import(filename);
        lfd := lo_open(loid,262144);
        lsize := lo_lseek(lfd,0,2);
        perform lo_lseek(lfd,0,0);
        content := loread(lfd,lsize);
        perform lo_close(lfd);
        perform lo_unlink(loid);
 
        return xmlparse(document convert_from(content,'UTF8'));
    end;
$f$;
```

So I should be able to import my file into this:

```
CREATE TABLE xbrl_reports
(
  id serial primary key NOT NULL,
  doc xml NOT NULL,
  cik varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

With this:

```
insert into xbrl_reports(doc, cik) values(xml_import('filepath/filename.xml'), '1');
```

But when I do the latter, I get this:

```
ERROR:  invalid XML document
DETAIL:  line 1: Start tag expected, '<' not found
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
^
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function xml_import(text) line 16 at RETURN
SQL state: 2200M
```

Comment: There is no example of xml data in your question. So it could be rightfully that xml file is not imported. Check content of source file, if it looks correct - check encoding of file

Comment: The error message correctly identifies the opening tag of the XML file (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>) so I'm assuming that's not it.

Comment: Hm. Can you edit a file, remove first line and try to import it again?

Comment: Tried that - same thing. I've tried complex XML files and very basic ones, and every time it tells me "'<' not found" on line 1, even though the file clearly opens with a well-formed tag.

Comment: It looks like UTF16-BE instead of UTF-8. Can you check first bytes of file, e.g. with `hexdump` what is in first bytes? Is that `3f3c` (utf-8) or `fffe 3c00 3f00` (utf18-be) or something else?

Comment: Doesn't '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' clearly establish that it's UTF-8?

Comment: You can write whatever you want inside file and then encode in whatever encoding you want. Look on output of `hexdump [yourfile]` to be sure

Comment: I don't know how to do that, but when I open the file in Notepad, it says UTF-8 in the panel on the bottom right.

Comment: So you're on Windows. You can install `hexdump` of course, especially with WSL. But I see hexdump as online service - https://www.fileformat.info/tool/hexdump.htm